# Can't type on bluetoothctl

Tags: linux, bluetooth

My OS is Arch Linux. I just trying to use the bluetooth of my laptop using the terminal. I used `bluetoothctl`command, but I can't type anymore on it. I also run it with root privilege.

```
[x@X ~]$ sudo bluetoothctl
[sudo] password for X: 
[bluetooth]#
```

I also check my bluetooth daemon using the `systemctl status bluetooth`command and it print something that I don't know what it is and I also don't know what to do next.

```
[x@X ~]$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

Answer (score 10):

Your bluetooth service is dead [ `Active: inactive (dead)` ], so you can't use it.

To get it active and running [ `Active: active (running)` ], just do the following:

- Load the generic bluetooth driver, if not already loaded by typing the following in your terminal:

  ```
  sudo modprobe btusb
  ```
- Start the bluetooth service:

  ```
  sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
  ```

Check the status again [ `systemctl status bluetooth.service` ] and you should find it's now active and running [ `Active: active (running)` ]

Answer (score 2):

Your bluetoothd is not running, try `sudo systemctl start bluetooth`

Answer (score 0):

This must be a security feature... it's really annoying when dealing with a SOC device with only one USB port, that reboots whenever you change the USB device due to constrained power...

```
chip@chip:~$ systemctl status bluetooth
� bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-12-27 04:17:24 UTC; 44min ago
Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 394 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
       ��394 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

chip@chip:~$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]#
```

Can't type! Works fine on terminal... just remotely it doesn't.

Solution for me was:

```
chip@chip:~$ sudo bluetoothctl
```